# Switch after 5 characters

Tags: c#, textchanged

I'm trying to swipe a card and after the 5 characters are entered I want it to go to the next textfield. I'm scanning a card.

Currently I have:

```
private void membernumber1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

But this changes it right after it enters one character, is there anyway to make it switch after 5 characters entered?

Comment: Errr... check the length of the text entered so far?

Comment: Does it have to be done with C#?

Comment: That's a bad design.  Having a single large textbox is _much_ more usable, and easier for you too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just count the number of characters in the `Text` property.  Using a counter won't work if they use the backspace key.

```
if( membernumber1.Text.Length == 5 )
    SwitchFocus();
```

Be aware though that this may not work for text that was pasted into the control (i.e., if it was > 5 characters).  You'll need proper validation for that case or you can just disable pasting, but validation is preferable as there are certainly other restrictions like being all numeric.